# GoogleSheets: как найти сумму чисел с символами?

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet

Есть столбец A:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Google Sheets нужно найти сумму: 90+6100+1310+0+3450+2*1000000
Если в поле ничего нет, то его содержимое равно 0.

Решение, которое смог собрать из примеров в интернете не работает:

```
=IF(RIGHT(I2,1)="k",SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(I2:I6,FIND(" ",I2:I6)-1)))*1000)
```

Не получается сделать:

- сравнивать с "k" каждый столбец(а не только I2) и в зависимости от этого умножать на 1 / 10^3 / 10^6;
- складывать все числа, не только с символами
- чтобы сумма находилась для всего столбца: а не до заданного руками N

Comment: Ваш пример - совсем не пример. Почему умножать на 10^3,  10^6? Буква всегда одна в ячейке? Всегда после цифр (или послеодной цифры)? Пробел есть/нет? Покажите ссылку на таблицу. Покажите в таблице желаемый результат. Уточните описание задачи с учетом заданных вопросов.

Comment: @vikttur
"Почему умножать на 10^3, 10^6"
k - тысяча
m - милион

"Буква всегда одна в ячейке?" - может не быть буквы. Но если есть, то всегда одна и после цифр.

Пробелов нет.

Ссылка на таблицу: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pmXl5C_8ezbepDTUQAOtBploozyttqmoWc6qbwTZxgU/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правый символ числовой, возвращаем число, иначе умножаем на 10 в степени, зависящей от правого символа-буквы:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(-RIGHT(A2:A)),A2:A,LEFT(A2:A,LEN(A2:A)-1)*10^IF(RIGHT(A2:A)="k",3,6))))
```

Если в ссылке на диапазон не указывать строку окончания диапазона, то формула будет просчитывать все строки в используемом диапазоне. В *Excel* такой прием не пройдет, там нужно определять последнюю строку. Указывать весь столбец не рекомендуется - не все функции умеют сами определять используемый диапазон и формула будеть молотить по всем строкам листа.

Comment: Спасибо! А почему результат не меняется, когда в пустую ячейку A5 заношу цифру?

Comment: В формуле была ошибка. Устранена

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает!

Comment: Хотя странно работает. Задал ему реальные данные и формула почему-то получила дробный ответ

Comment: Нормально работает. А то, что в строке 48 значение 3.28, Вас не смущает? )